# CakePHP override Auth in Controller to use BasicAuthenticate getUser() function

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp-2.5

My "Auth" is set in the AppController (to use Form) for all of my controllers. I have one "special" controller which needs to use BasicAuthenticate and then getUser().

With this in the controller: public $components = array( 'Auth' => array( 'authenticate' => array('Basic') ) );

And this in the function: $newUser = $this->Auth->Basic->getUser(); or $newUser = $this->Auth->getUser();

I keep getting the error "Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object".

How do I override the "Auth" set in the AppController for just one of the controllers so that I can use getUser()?

Comment: What version of CakePHP are you working with?

Comment: Sorry, I thought I added that. It's version 2.5.2.

Comment: Nevermind, I just did this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21745320/cakephp-authentication-on-rest-api